# How would I add type to nested object

Tags: typescript

How can I add types for a nested object, that looks like this.

```
const theme: DefaultTheme = {
    color: {
        primary: '#5039E7',
        secondary: '#372E4B',
        heading: '#4D5062',
    },
    font: {
        size: {
            extraLarge: '7.2rem',
            large: '5.2rem',
            medium: '3.6rem',
            small: '2.4rem',
            hyperlink: '1.8rem',
            paragraph: '1.6rem',
        },
        family: 'sans-serif',
    },
 };
```

I did it like so, but feel like this is not a good aproach to add types to an Object

```
interface DefaultTheme {
    color: {
        primary: string;
        secondary: string;
        heading: string;
    };
    font: {
       size: {
         extraLarge: string;
         large: string;
         medium: string;
         small: string;
         hyperlink: string;
         paragraph: string;
        };
        family: string;
    };
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's "not a good approach"? Answering that could lead you to solutions that you like better.

Comment: it is very verbose, i'm not very familiar with all possibilities of a TypeScript, so i thought maybe some one know's more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is totally fine. But here is my approach.

```
 interface ColorInterface<T> {
     primary: T;
     secondary: T;
     heading: T;
 }

 interface SizeInterface<T> {
    extraLarge: T;
    large: T;
    medium: T;
    small: T;
    hyperlink: T;
    paragraph: T;
 }

 interface FontInterface<T> {
     size: SizeInterface<T>,
     family: T;
 }

 interface DefaultThemeInterface<T> {
     color: ColorInterface<T>,
     font: FontInterface<T>
 }




const theme: DefaultThemeInterface<string> = {
    color: {
        primary: '#5039E7',
        secondary: '#372E4B',
        heading: '#4D5062',
    },
    font: {
        size: {
            extraLarge: '7.2rem',
            large: '5.2rem',
            medium: '3.6rem',
            small: '2.4rem',
            hyperlink: '1.8rem',
            paragraph: '1.6rem',
        },
        family: 'sans-serif',
    },
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer splitting each object into a different Interface is a pretty good idea. What do you suggest to use for such an object `Interface` or rather `type`?

Comment: for now you can use type but if you need to extend them then go for interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating models for nested objects also and giving the type as those models is a clean approach

```
interface DefaultTheme {
    color: Color;
    font: Font;
}

interface Color {
    primary: string;
    secondary: string;
    heading: string;
}

interface FontSize {
    extraLarge: string;
    large: string;
    medium: string;
    small: string;
    hyperlink: string;
    paragraph: string;
}

interface Font {
    size: FontSize;
    family: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some weird TypeScript validator:

```js
type HexNumber = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
type HexString = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f'
type StringNumber<T extends number> = `${T}`
type HEX = HexNumber | StringNumber<HexNumber> | HexString;

type Check<T extends string, Cache extends readonly string[] = []> =
    T extends `${infer A}${infer Rest}`
    ? A extends HEX
    ? Check<Rest, [...Cache, A]> : A extends ''
    ? 1 : 2 : T extends '' ? Cache extends { length: 6 }
    ? Cache : never : never;

type Elem = string;

type Mapper<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Result extends string = ''
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends Elem
    ? `${Result}${H}`
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? H extends Elem
    ? Mapper<Tail, `${Result}${H}`>
    : never
    : never
    : never;


type Result = Mapper<Check<'abcdef'>> // allow
type Result2 = Mapper<Check<'00cdef'>> // allow
type Result3 = Mapper<Check<'z0cdef'>> // not allow
type Result4 = Mapper<Check<'00cdem'>> // not allow
type Result5 = Mapper<Check<'aaaaa'>> // to few arguments

type Color<S extends string> = {
    primary: S;
    secondary: S;
    heading: S;
}

type Size<T extends string> = {
    extraLarge: T;
    large: T;
    medium: T;
    small: T;
    hyperlink: T;
    paragraph: T;
}

interface DefaultTheme<C extends string, S extends string> {
    color: Color<C>;
    font: {
        size: Size<S>;
        family: string;
    };
}

type RemoveHash<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer Hash}${infer Rest}`
    ? Hash extends '#' ? Rest
    : never
    : never;

const theme = {
    color: {
        primary: '#5039E7',
        secondary: '#372E4B',
        heading: '#4D5062',
    },
    font: {
        size: {
            extraLarge: '7.2rem',
            large: '5.2rem',
            medium: '3.6rem',
            small: '2.4rem',
            hyperlink: '1.8rem',
            paragraph: '1.6rem',
        },
        family: 'sans-serif',
    },
} as const;


type HEXValidation<T extends string> = Check<RemoveHash<T>> extends string[] ? Mapper<Check<RemoveHash<T>>> extends RemoveHash<T> ? [] : [never] : [never]

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type IsRem<T extends string> = T extends `${number}.${number}rem` ? 1 : 2;

type UNITvalidation<T> = IsUnion<T> extends true ? [never] : [];



declare function validator<T extends string, S extends string>
    (config: DefaultTheme<T, S>, ...flag:[...HEXValidation<T>, ...UNITvalidation<IsRem<S>>]):void;

const result = validator(theme) // ok

/**
 * Tests
 */
const result2=validator({
    ...theme,
    font:{
        ...theme.font,
        size:{
            ...theme.font.size,
             paragraph: '1.6rm', // <---error because of type, should be rem
        }

    }
})

const result3=validator({
    ...theme,
    color:{
        ...theme.color,
        primary: '#5039E-', // <--- error becaue of invalid HEX
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeA5ArgWwEYQE5QLxQAYoAfKARhKgCZKBmSgFkoFZKA2SgdkoA5KBOAFChIsBAGVgWAJYA7AOZ4oAcgCCyysoBCG0soDCulQBEjygKJmAYmYCGZ9GYDGZgCZmIZgGbLh4aJIyCigY2AA8ACpQCMAQsq4AzlCyaJhYAHxKAAYAJADeEQC%20WX6iMOYAGkpwSKnYlIFy8iFpYTUt2JmkNY0KANyCpdD6ABYQTgDWkdHwsfFJCVJNADRQ%20rZOYzNziVBYELauAPayADYgUItB8gDaALpK95m4glBvUFExcbu5eXJe9VUhXy-3qACUIItiq93gB%20KCqbbfJLlCowt7w0bjKYQxarG4AOiJ602EFWqjumQAXAikfMVL53lB4RQaTQaZ9ZsiGcy1hstl96XkoKc4vJgCMaRxCujeSStjTZBAAG71RUq7ADIZQcyi1BKK5NLUiaAAWVsYEgWDCstUWBwgt2EMOJ3OdqwthAYV1EFQ6WWstxyFOwDpu0NCiUykZ72eCPtYaS91l8KDIdlNPdiagN1BOBgdxTsGzPtQRd%20aeAwLyMGhTPVqqwGfjDq59P2LrOF1zsgB%20dWRIJeY%20tmkp0LTPhEVHp2zzuOXfdnu9evSRZgJb1RfNlvC07HqwrkODVfytaya-ryQ1TavSsbzfvmsG2srSh3VrCWMmYWUtnQTiuBAPjpJkAD0YFQLYpynEcADur7HiGND4B%204TflMygEAQgHAcooFQBBUEwfBiEJCe9CoRan4Yb%20ABeOFASB4GQbIRyhtBsEISaUCVkwVG7tatFYYxvr4SxyTscRXFkSerACTRYw-n%20tiqfYBFEcARxQACcFQVg8hoHEwAJIMPH6EcsHWuI2YRvIcZ5LKYAyKgthYCANLiAMTIJOMJyuG5HlQF5spjIcTSeQMMrauI0h0RA0yOgsSwKA5soxB6AAybnyBAHLee8pw5XlHwFW8qAQK40hoPlsoJK5MG1UyIz%20FgpxyBMTXvGAbm2PIHpgJKpWCNFcixFgXgbNAxjAbYJ4RGMFVfrZKXyKsNlJZcq2ZI5TJOJZRxYDSFlWV%206RlTpJzADSu1Mu8CRxSVsXxWE4jnbKTKTagY5BXZF2FFFZn%20LxvpHKqMC2AkIyJW24bbXgsqcjsSS-MOENQ9Ww64lWJSTrAkMjNmygAMQaKmkLAI%20N5U42Wr7bIixQBKvrQPgt1vPtVk3R93UuYFNIk8wBC0Pw5icMoAZ3fdfnxPzKjE7QnBUOYDA6JLUtQGFVUKALxMMMYQtsFQEuyoU6tvF4V3cxrlyPdbNvvBltjZQZJXKJwBJUPsqAmw7hXFQLzCe97vt%201AFVVTVKi0ASbAh%20bDv1ZxAtUASDDxzzUstVa7WyJ1KhkASPAZ2HUA9R6-UWkNyiF3HYkJ0yZuZzptjfecAsJLYDMALS%20TIPgJ03hRQUk9OLFq2qogAatB0gBcA0gnDDyNbdcca0RCqBgxA6PQxEBGbXZ9y8mhQlKTioPgwTkSgZkm2b9vu837yx80jcT5YA8b8f4WghEU4%20wqomSgPII4kImbaRGMAYAYAEhUggosDYExt4TS4gSfaqAwK2DAkLRWzAqA8DYNqAAqrIResgIhHAAJKyHGr5JwC8l7ELjAACmIdmLuFx4QsPzsQgAlHgTIyojhzygA2bAAjNosNlPnYcVDBACNwEIkRrgizyLvDeAYPEqEJFIeQ5%20%20AbgRAeJtG4eiTiUJoXQ8YjDZA3wePCSapxfJiKZlgZAEBjTAx0ZvZe3I7JxiRtyX4KRQhYEKASfIoS0iFG9lkXkrJqBeNEMQxAVCIjKlnvPfR%208lA6PMXY3Jm0pAeJfj-Vx9wJ6CCAk4Iq%20wdLIFkAw8hUBMntXnodPx9I7LrRWmvWULD6ZeGkPIGkM1JrzUWglCI61-RQEHF4IqozCREmnlk2wtib4DiJKk9JbS54bP0T430r1QJ3D4VSYRc86YnEZvsciIYlD7I6VgFhzMKoCKIkcCYgwwIACo-mvD%20R8CmpkoB-LAoIMeoZ7knioLgZ5GzDosPZvMok7yySyktrQqkqKmSDgxQSbFwAG73TtnijWBKplEqugSB68VSUa3Ln1Aa1da5YB9qsIiYRu68uwFgQ6UBMBODmi4o4Xgmb%20FWFDI4wZXBCugN7Zu0VG4jT4YMaFewkLAFoAi9ZWlXmoqpSzBOnNDq4ubsaiq6CDpYEZWXPm7lda4NFt3CWhFII8t5dEe0grhVzWgOKqAchnmwEqKbNVQA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/hex-validation) you can find explanation to HEX validation